# winsock error code 10060 exchange 2013

Tags: email, exchange-server, exchange-server-2013

I just setup an exchange 2013 server, and have an intenret send connector using my mx records, no smarthost, i have cu9 installed, but am getting an error in my exchange quque

error encountered while communicating with primary target ip address: "failed to connect, Winsock error code, 10061, win32 error code 10061"

I have installed ad and dns on this server too, i have read some other posts, and people said they recreated their sent connector, i tried that but mail is still stuck

Im not sure on what more information is needed but happy to share it

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out, this was spam coming in, email was flowing fine.